# file_get_contents memory issue

Tags: php

I'm using file_get_contents just to call a php file (which returns some data); like that:

`file_get_contents('http://example.com/foo.php');` and NOT e.g. `$holding_var = file_get_contents('http://example.com/foo.php');`

Will it use the assigned memory of 20kB (let's say the meant file called by my script returns a 10kB response) or will not use the memory at all since the result is not stored in any variable?

Comment: Why don't you just `include` the script you are trying to call instead of reading it's contents?

Comment: try using HTTP_Request: pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2

Answer (score 2):

The code as you have it written, will just open the file on disk, read it's contents, and then do nothing with it.

Yes, it will use up the assigned memory of 20kb, but then it will be freed by the php runtime garbage collector at some point.

I don't understand why you would ever write code like this though.  It won't execute the code in the .php file.

Comment: thanks for the info; actually it's file_get_contents('http://example.com/foo.php');

Comment: It can be useful if foo.php is executing some code on the other server.

Comment: @McRonald ahh, makes much more sense now that you added the url. You should explicitly include the http:// as well